# why my argparse program do not continue to do the next lines?

Tags: python, lxml, argparse

BSD

hi guys, i wrote a program that takes arguments with argparse and the stores it in variables,
then the variables contents is used to be passed out to an XML file that i want to create;
gere is a snippet from my code:

```
    import argparse
    from lxml import etree

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        my_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        my_parser.add_argument('U', type=str, action='store', help='Enter the account user name')
        my_parser.add_argument('P', type=str, action='store', help='Enter the account password')
        my_parser.add_argument('i', type=str, action='store', help='Enter the phone Number To Send 
    the SMS')
        my_parser.add_argument('k', type=str, action='store', help='Enter the senders phone 
    number')
        my_parser.add_argument('data', type=str, action='store', help='Enter the text for SMS')
        my_parser.add_argument('e', type=str, action='store', help='send sms?')
        args = my_parser.parse_args()
        username = args.U
        password = args.P
        phone = args.i
        reply = args.k
        data = args.data
        #print(args.U, args.P, args.i, args.k, args.data)
        if args.e:
            # Create the root element
            page = etree.Element('sms')

            # Make a new document tree
            doc = etree.ElementTree(page)
    
            # Add the subelements
            pageElement1 = etree.SubElement(page, 'Account')
            subelement2 = etree.SubElement(pageElement1, 'id').text = username
            subelement3 = etree.SubElement(pageElement1, 'password').text = password

            # Add the subelements for "Attributes" tree
            pageElement2 = etree.SubElement(page, 'Attributes')
            subelement4 = etree.SubElement(pageElement2, 'reference').text = '123'
            subelement5 = etree.SubElement(pageElement2, 'replyPath').text = reply

            # Save to XML file
            doc.write('output.xml', xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

when i run it from the CMD, it runs only the first part, but the XML part is not executed.

can someone plz help?

thanks

Comment: `args.e` may be 'False' - this can explain why the xml part is not executed.

Comment: If you are happy with the display of `print(args)`, then the issue isn't with the `argparse` part.  You have shown how this you run this (in CMD), nor the `args` values.  Also it isn't clear what you mean by "first part" and "XML part".  Remember, you are asking people who can't run your code, and can't read your mind or look over your shoulder as you run it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue according to me is when you are running the command you are not sending value from command prompt for **e**. Try using following command:-

```
python your_filename.py e="your value"
```

or you can also use following command:-

```
python your_filename.py --e "your value"
```

And print out the value of args.e